# How to prevent CKEDITOR autosaving textarea/contenteditable contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, ckeditor

[image: Firefox Autosave recover confirmation dialog]

I am using CKEDITOR plugin to provide format toolbar. So I guess that above is a built in message provided by CKEDITOR.

In my web application I want User to use a blank textarea when he/she visit the page. CKEDITOR allows user to continue from the last edit. How do I disable this?

And I am Using a "contentedible" div.

Comment: Sorry I misled you with my question. autocomplete doesn't seem to be working on contentedible divs.

Comment: Does your content editable div contains any tags or something?

Comment: Yes a <p> with "Hello there" within it.

Comment: my answer is edited check it and let me know

Comment: This is not normal browser behavior but caused by some software you are using. It is not reproducable using a simple HTML page with a contenteditable element. Please provide the code of a demo HTML document that produces the effect and specify the browser version(s) and platforms tested .

Comment: This prompt is displayed by [AutoSave](http://ckeditor.com/addon/autosave), a 3rd party CKEditor plugin. Remove that plugin from your CKEditor config (i.e. use `config.removePlugins = 'autosave'` or similar) to get rid of that thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **autocomplete** form element attribute with value **"off"**. This might not work if the users have installed some plugins to save the entered text.

```
<form autocomplete="off"
```

Comment: Thank You @addy2601 for the answer.
is there a way that I can add/remove this feature with jquery attr function?
Because I need to change this dynamically. And I'm using a contentedible div.

Comment: @shan A content editable div is absolutely **not** the same as a textarea form input. If that is what you are having trouble with then you should change the question to reflect that. As it is you appear to be asking one thing, whilst your actual problem is another.

Comment: It's my bad. I've Updated the question now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can simply do that by using **autocomplete="off"**. set this to your form but keep in mind, this will disable your auto-completion in another browsers as well

**Edited based on new question:**

This will clear all divs inside the content editable. use it properly to clear individual elements.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#t > p').html('');
})
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer. But Sorry I misled you with my question. autocomplete doesn't seem to be working on contentedible divs.

Comment: But the browser asks the same question from the user, everytime he/she revisits. How can I prevent that message. autocomplete=off doesn't do that.

Comment: usually this will clear every text in P Tag. but i don't think we can control these type of browser functionality. can you clear the cache and try again? but im not sure btw.

Comment: negative. I cleared cache.

Comment: Just read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( document ).on( 'focus', ':input', function(){
    $( this ).attr( 'autocomplete', 'off' );
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks But,
Sorry I misled you with my question. autocomplete doesn't seem to be working on contentedible divs.

Comment: @shan:can you create fiddle for same??